# How to find the minimum value between two dates and put into new column using Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have `2` dataset

```
# df1 - minute based dataset

date                  Open
2018-01-01 00:00:00   1.0516 
2018-01-01 00:01:00   1.0516 
2018-01-01 00:02:00   1.0516 
2018-01-01 00:03:00   1.0516 
2018-01-01 00:04:00   1.0516 
....

# df2 - daily based dataset

date_from             date_to
2018-01-01            2018-01-01 02:21:00
2018-01-02            2018-01-02 01:43:00
2018-01-03            NA
2018-01-04            2018-01-04 03:11:00
2018-01-05            2018-01-05 00:19:00
```

For each value in `df2`, `date_from` and `date_to`, I want to grab the `minimum/low` value in `Open` in `df1` and put it in a new column in `df2` called `min_value`

`df1` is a minute based sorted dataset.

For the  `NA` in `date_to` in `df2`, we can skip those row entirely and move to the next row.

**What did I do?**

- Firstly I tried to find values between two dates.
- after that I used this code:

  ```
  df2['min_value'] =
   df1[df1['date'].dt.hour.between(df2['date_from'], df2['date_to'])].min()
  ```

I wanted to search `between` two dates but I am not sure if that is how to do it.

however it does not work. Could you please help identify what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this works for you?

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2018-01-01 00:00:00', '2018-01-01 00:01:00', '2018-01-01 00:02:00', '2018-01-01 00:03:00','2018-01-01 00:04:00'],
                   'Open':[1.0516, 1.0516, 1.0516, 1.0516, 1.0516]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'date_from':['2018-01-01', '2018-01-02', '2018-01-03', '2018-01-04','2018-01-05'],
                   'date_to':['2018-01-01 02:21:00', '2018-01-02 01:43:00', np.nan,
                              '2018-01-04 03:11:00', '2018-01-05 00:19:00']})

## converting to datetime
df1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date'])
df1.set_index('date', inplace=True)
df2['date_from'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['date_from'])
df2['date_to'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['date_to'])

def func(val):
    minimum_val = np.nan
    minimum_date = np.nan
    if val['date_from'] is pd.NaT or val['date_to'] is pd.NaT:
        pass
    minimum_val = df1[val['date_from'] : val['date_to']]['Open'].min()
    if  minimum_val is not np.nan:
        minimum_date = df1[val['date_from'] : val['date_to']].reset_index().head(1)['date'].values[0]
        pass
    else:
        pass
    return pd.DataFrame({'date_from':[val['date_from']], 'date_to':[val['date_to']], 'Open': [minimum_val], 'min_date': [minimum_date]})

df3=pd.concat(list(df2.apply(func, axis=1)))
```

Comment: Thanks so much for composing the answer. I also want to know the `FIRST` corresponding `date` value of the `min` value.

Comment: cont... Basically there could be many same `min` values but I just want the `date` of the first.

Answer (score 0):

Following codesnap is readable.

```
import pandas as pd

def get_minimum_value(row, df):
    temp = df[(df['date'] >= row['date_from']) & (df['date'] <= row['date_to'])]
    return temp['value'].min()

df1 = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("test2.csv")

df1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date'])
df2['date_from'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['date_from'])
df2['date_to'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['date_to'])
df2['value'] = df2.apply(func=get_minimum_value, df=df1, axis=1)
```

Here `df2.apply()` function sent each row as first argument to `get_minimum_value` function. Applying this to your given data, result is:

```
   date_from             date_to   value
0 2018-01-01 2018-01-01 02:21:00  1.0512
1 2018-01-02 2018-01-02 01:43:00     NaN
2 2018-01-03                 NaT     NaN
3 2018-01-04 2018-01-04 03:11:00     NaN
4 2018-01-05 2018-01-05 00:19:00     NaN
```